# Django ClassBasedViews without html file?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

How to avoid producing html files with content like this:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Can I define somehow it in views or forms, so that there is no need for creating this files in templates?

Comment: It's easy (see my answer) but I'm quite curious why you would avoid creating html files for a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most class-based views use the `TemplateResponseMixin`. You can override the `render_to_response` method to return a `HttpResponse` object (or any subclass) that doesn't render a template.

```
class SimpleResponseMixin(object):
    def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse(content='<content>', content_type=kwargs.get('content_type', self.content_type))
```